# Bootstrap 4 link hover underline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 adds the `text-decoration: underline;` property to the anchor tags on hover only.

Is there a helper or utility class that removes it?

I just created a helper class for my css to remove it but I want to check if there was one already that existed and maybe I am overlooking it.

```
/* My helper class */
.no-underline:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Default behaviour of browsers is to underline links

Comment: Right but Bootstrap removes it, but adds underline on hover. I was just wondering if there was a helper class in their framework that remove it instead of creating my own.

Comment: Yes, you can use `nav-link` class on a element to remove underline on hover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a variable for this in Bootstrap 4 `$link-hover-decoration`. So, if you are building Bootstrap yourself, you can set it to `none`. Here are other available variables:

```
a {
  color: $link-color;
  text-decoration: $link-decoration;
  background-color: transparent; // Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.

  @include hover {
    color: $link-hover-color;
    text-decoration: $link-hover-decoration;
  }
}
```